# Dynamically rewrite path in nignx

Tags: nginx, next.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use a nextjs server to render depend on domain-name, the dynamic router I set expects to be `[domainname]/.../...`

the goal is to create an Nginx config that adds the hostname as the first path in the URL if not exist.
For example:

- if URL = `a.com/product/a` it needs to change to `a.com/a.com/product/a`
- if URL = `z.com` -> `z.com/z.com`
- etc ...

the following script did that but only for "a.com" as it's hardcoded. how I can make that dynamic, I mean whatever $host is.

also how I can do all that without changing the actual URL in the client browser?

```
roxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;

upstream nextjs_upstream {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name a.com b.com;

  server_tokens off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  location /_next/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;

    # For testing cache - remove before deploying to production
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
  }

  location /static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

  location / {
    if ($request_uri !~* "^/a.com.*") {
        add_header X-see "special";
        rewrite (.*) /$host/$1 break;
     }


    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with next.js - is it feasible to just use the Host header instead of rewriting the URL?

Comment: it's possible yes, but we will not be able to benefit from the incremental static regeneration. that's why i want to have it in URL.

Comment: Use a regular expression that matches a domain name but not the expected second parameter. For example, if the domain name always includes a dot, use `^/[^/]+\.`